# Put multiple segments of URL in 1 variable with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, routes

For a new application I'd like to work with the URI to determine what content should be loaded. Nothing special so far ... But how can I let the slug have slash(es) in it and make sure Zend Framework sees them as 1 variable? ZF splits the requested URL in chunks where every part is the string between 2 slashed. Now I'd like to have all the parts in 1 variable to work with.

For Example:

```
/de/my/page

de > language
my/page > 1 variable
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: `explode('/','$url, 1);` possibly 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Advice from Hari K is the best choice, but if you really want to keep your slash, you can work with a Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex to catch your parameter, you just need to find a good regexp, a simple example :

```
$routetotry = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex('([^/]+)/(.*)',
                    array(1 => 'de', 'controller' => 'someController', 'action' => 'someAction'),
                    array(1 => 'lang',2=>'my_variable_with_slash'),
                    '%s/%s'
);

$router->addRoute('routetotry', $routetotry);
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom router. Most flexible solution, but not the easiest one :(

Answer (score 0):

Replace the slashes in the slug with someother value of your choice.

For example hyphen ( - ) or underscore ( _ ) .